# Assignment from incompatible pointer type with structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, incompatibletypeerror

I have a function where I have the lines in `scope.c`, and is failing on the third line with an incompatible pointer type error.

```
struct scope* newScope = malloc(sizeof(struct scope));
newScope->symbols = createSymbolTable();
newScope->st = createSyntaxTree();
```

The struct scope in `scope.h` is defined as:

```
struct scope {
    char *id;
    struct symboltable* symbols;
    struct symboltree*  st;
    struct symboltable* strings;
};
```

And the prototype for the function createSyntaxTree() in `syntax.h` is

```
struct syntaxtree* createSyntaxTree();
```

I could understand having issues if I were dealing with typedefs, but this is pretty straightfoward, and the types on both sides are of type `syntaxtree*`.

How do I solve this frustrating error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type of `scope::st` is `struct symboltree*`. The return type of `createSyntaxTree()` is `struct syntaxtree*`. They are different types. Hence,

```
newScope->st = createSyntaxTree();
```

is a problem.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
struct syntaxtree*  st;
```

instead of

```
struct symboltree*  st;
```

when defining `struct scope`.

Comment: Lord almighty...you are correct.  Thank you for pointing out the error and for the speedy response.  Obviously I've been awake for far too long.